# Error while building an android app using vscode

Tags: javascript

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAF8W.png)

please help me resolve my problem to finish building my application this week